# Table data is blank when using 2 JOIN in sql

Tags: sql, mysql

I have problem with my data table which is blank when I am using the 2 JOIN sql in my PHP code.

Table when using 2 JOINs:

[image]

Table when using single JOIN:

[image]

here picture example of database

tblleaves

[image]

tblemployees

[image]

tbldepartments

[image]

I'm using 2 JOINs because my database which is tbldepartment and tblemployees is from different db table.

here is my query using single JOIN :-

```
SELECT 
tblleaves.id AS lid, 
tblemployees.FirstName,
tblemployees.LastName,
tblemployees.EmpId,
tblemployees.id,
tblleaves.LeaveType,
tblleaves.PostingDate,
tblleaves.Status 
FROM tblleaves
JOIN tblemployees ON tblleaves.empid = tblemployees.id
WHERE tblleaves.Status = :status
ORDER BY lid DESC
```

and this when using 2 JOINs:

```
SELECT 
tblleaves.id AS lid, 
tblemployees.FirstName,
tblemployees.LastName,
tblemployees.EmpId,
tblemployees.id,
tbldepartments.Name AS Department,
tblleaves.LeaveType,
tblleaves.PostingDate,
tblleaves.Status 
FROM tblleaves
JOIN tblemployees ON tblleaves.empid = tblemployees.id
JOIN tbldepartments ON tblemployees.Department = tbldepartments.id 
WHERE tblleaves.Status = :status
ORDER BY lid DESC
```

any idea how this actually happen?

Comment: It seems that `tblemployees.Department = tbldepartments.id` doesn't have a match in this context. However, we have no idea what data is in your database, so we cannot check.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. This issue doesn't seem to have much relationship to PHP, by contrast.

Comment: `any idea how this actually happen?`...it happens when none of the rows in the database meet the condition in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`. But as mentioned above, you didn't show us any of your data so we can't comment on it.

Comment: *here is my code using single JOIN* Add `tblemployees.Department` to the output list and show the output.

Comment: Provide data as text please, not pictures- see [ask]

Comment: Anyway it's trivially obvious that `tblemployees.Department = tbldepartments.id` will never work because `tblemployees.Department` contains descriptions of departments, and `tbldepartments.id` contains IDs. None of those values will ever match, you can see just by looking at any of the rows. Your `tblemployees` table should contain the department _IDs_, as a foreign key, not the descriptions. You perhaps need to study the topics of database design and normalisation a bit more carefully.